# F# - Combine Multiple Column String Lists Into Array

Tags: arrays, list, f#

I have a number of column string lists (11), which I would like to combine into a single array:

```
[List1]
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie

[List2]
3
5
7

[List3]
11
13
17
```

for export to csv file:

```
[Array]
Alpha     3   11
Bravo     5   13
Charlie   7   17
```

Is this possible and, if so,  how?

Comment: Which particular part of this problem are you stuck on?

Comment: John, the first part - combining column lists into an array?

Comment: Hint: look for a  ``transpose`` function. It will help if you write the signatures of the input and output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically you want to transpose. You can write your own function or use something from a Matrix library or Deedle. This is easy to do with a for comprehension as well. You will need to first map all elements of the list to be strings. Finally use `String.concat` to join the elements of the array:

```
let list1 = ["Alpha";"Bravo";"Charlie"]
let list2 = ["3";"5";"7"]
let list3 = ["11";"13";"17"]

let lists = [list1;list2;list3] // create a list of lists

[|for i in [0 .. (lists.Length - 1)] do
    for j in [0 .. (lists.[i].Length - 1)] do 
    yield lists.[j].[i] // swap rows and columns
|] 
|> Array.splitInto (lists.Length) // 
|> Array.map (fun x -> String.concat "," x) // join the array elements with a comma for CSV output.
```

Output:

```
// val it : string [] = [|"Alpha,3,11"; "Bravo,5,13"; "Charlie,7,17"|]
```

After this you can just use `File.WriteAllLines` or a similar method to dump this into a file.

**Edit:**
Let's add list4:

```
let list4 = ["19";"23";"29"]
let lists = [list1;list2;list3;list4]
```

If you think about it for a bit, you will realize that you want the first element of each list, basically its head:

```
lists
|> List.map List.head
//val it : string list = ["Alpha"; "3"; "11"; "19"]
```

Now if you could jus thread this function through the remaining part of the list (once you take the head, you have the tail left), so for the next row:

```
lists 
|> List.map List.tail
|> List.map List.head
//val it : string list = ["Bravo"; "5"; "13"; "23"]
```

Now if you could just repeat this until you ran out of lists...you actually can, with recursion:

```
let rec transpose xs =
    match xs with
    []::xs -> []
    | xs -> List.map List.head xs :: transpose (List.map List.tail xs)

transpose lists
|> Array.ofList
|> Array.map (fun x -> String.concat "," x)

//val it : string list list =
//[["Alpha"; "3"; "11"; "19"]; ["Bravo"; "5"; "13"; "23"];
// ["Charlie"; "7"; "17"; "29"]]

//val it : string [] =  [|"Alpha,3,11,19"; "Bravo,5,13,23"; "Charlie,7,17,29"|]
```

Comment: It appears to fail if I add another list - let list4 = ["19";"23";"29"]! Am I missing something?

Comment: @matekus yes, you would get an index out of bounds error. That's why it's not a good idea to use positional indexing. It's helpful though to indicate _how_ it appears to fail.  I'll add a version that uses recursion, if you could rewrite it with a `fold` that would be great. :-)